# Using urlencode to escape periods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urlencode

I'm writing a tool in Python to query an online database. The database expects that all parameter values with have periods escaped. For example:

```
{
    "param1": "test..value"
}
```

should be queried as

```
param1=test%5C.%5C.value
```

However, urlencode will not include the escape character "%5C" for periods, leading to:

```
param1=test..value
```

Is there any way to tell urlencode to escape all periods?

Alternatively, I can just use a string replace to escape the periods before calling urlencode, but I'm curious if there's a way to have urlencode do it automatically.

Comment: That’s backslash escaping, nothing to do with URL-encoding periods (which would look like `param1=test%2E%2Evalue`). `urlencode` definitely will not do it.

Comment: If the query is a Python-compatible regular expression or close enough, `re.escape` escapes text as regular expressions.

Comment: @Ry- I see what you're saying. It's weird because the online query builder for this database will have the value as "test..value" but in the URL it appears as "test%5C.%5C.value". I will probably just have to add the backslash using string replace